# Problem regarding outer measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu^*$ be an outer measure on a set $X$. We want to show that $E\subset X$ is $\mu^*$-measurable iff for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\mu^*$-measurable set $F\subset E$ such that $\mu^*(E\setminus F)<\epsilon$.

I started the problem as follows:

Consider that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\mu^*$-measurable set $F\subset E$ such that $\mu^*(E\setminus F)<\epsilon$.

For any $A\subset X$, we have

$\mu^*(A\cap E)+\mu^*(A\setminus E)\le \mu^*(E)+\mu^*(A)$. Also since $F$ is $\mu^*$-measurable, therefore, $\mu^*(E)=\mu^*(F)+\mu^*(E\setminus F)<\mu^*(F)+\epsilon$. Thus $\mu^*(E)\le \mu^*(F)$. Therefore $\mu^*(E)=\mu^*(F)$. But I could not proceed any further. Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: $$\mu^\ast(A\cap E) = \mu^\ast(A\cap E \cap F) + \mu^\ast ((A\cap E)\setminus F)$$

Comment: Yeah I got it...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to show is $\mu^\star(A) \geq \mu^\star(A \cap E) + \mu^\star(A \cap E^c)$ for any $A \subset X$ to show that $E$ is $\mu^\star$-measurable, since $\mu^\star(A) \leq \mu^\star(A \cap E) + \mu^\star(A \cap E^c)$ by subadditivity of the outer measure.

Here are some hints:

$\mu^\star(A\cap E) = \mu^\star(A\cap E \cap F) + \mu^\star(A\cap E \cap F^c)$ (as Daniel mentioned above) since we know $F$ is a $\mu^\star$-measurable set by assumption.

$E \cap F = F$ since $F \subset E$. So $\mu^\star(A \cap E \cap F) = \mu^\star(A \cap F)$.

$A \cap E \cap F^c \subset E\cap F^c$. So $\mu^\star(A \cap E \cap F^c) \leq \mu^\star(E \cap F^c)$, and we know something about that measure from the assumption.

Lastly, $E^c \subset F^c$ since $F \subset E$. So $A \cap E^c \subset A \cap F^c$ and $\mu^\star(A \cap E^c) \leq \mu^\star(A \cap F^c)$.

This should get you to the finish line.